# Why renaming a database is not possible

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to rename a database through SSMS and getting this below error:-

[image]

I am not realizing from the additional information

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform such statements as below.

```
    USE master;  
    GO  
    ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    GO
    ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase MODIFY NAME = MyTestDatabaseCopy ;
    GO  
    ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabaseCopy SET MULTI_USER
    GO
```

Comment: Database name can be modified by SSMS, but only in case if there are no active sessions in such database, but in general it is a way to perform rename

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in SSMS.

```
1.right click your database name.
2. properties
3. Options.
5. Restrict Access Select single.
```

then repeat the step to change again into MULTI_USER After renaming has been done.

Comment: Then the very first session will high-jack that single session again. More safe to perform rename as one session batch, like JERRY suggested

Comment: And learning the syntax of the commands is not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close all existing connections before to do that..

For this you can

- use SP_WHO and Kill all open connections to your database
  OR
- Take database offline: Right Click -> Tasks -> Take Offline -> Check Drop All Active Connections